# Update many rows using value from row I'm updating

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have to update value from rows which have this value greater than 10 and I need to subtract 5 from this value.
So I don't know how to get value I'm updating.

```
update MyTable
set MyValue = ((how to get value I'm updating)-5)
where MyValue > 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE MT
  SET MyValue = MT.MyValue - 5
FROM MyTable AS MT
WHERE MT.MyValue > 10
```

Comment: No alias is required.

Comment: ok, not required but looks and reads cleaner.  Will remove that comment.

Comment: Why not just `UPDATE MyTable SET MyValue=MyValue-5 WHERE MyValue>10`?  The alias doesn't seem to make it cleaner than that.

Comment: yours will work too, however I prefer the style of alias as it will work when I need to perform `JOINS`.  It's a consistent update syntax.

Comment: Good point. (why can't i just say "Good point." without SO saying I need to type 4 more characters?)

Comment: Omg. How could I not know that I can just use a value I'm updating. Thank you very much.